# Sanitizing url and parameters

Tags: validation, security, sanitization

Currently, my software has the following workflow

1. User performs an search through a REST API and selects an item
2. Server performs the same search again to validate the user's selection

In order to implement step 2, the user has to send the URL params that he used for his search as a string (ex. `age=10&gender=M`).

The server will then `http_get(url + "?" + params_str_submitted_by_user)`

Can a malicious user make the server connect to an unintended server by manipulating `params_str_submitted_by_user`?

What is the worst case scenario if even newlines are left in and the user can arbitrarily manipulate the HTTP headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are appending `params_str_submitted_by_user` to the base URL after the `?` delimiter, you are safe from this type of attack used where the context of the domain is changed to a username or password:

Say URL was `http://example.com` and `params_str_submitted_by_user` was `@evil.com` and you did not have the `/` or `?` characters in your URL string concatenation.

This would make your URL `http://example.com@evil.com` which actually means username `example.com` at domain `evil.com`.

However, [the username cannot contain the `?` (nor slash) character](http://www.w3.org/TR/url-1/#url-writing), so you should be safe as you are forcing the username to be concatenated. In your case URL becomes:

```
http://example.com?@evil.com
```

or

```
http://example.com/?@evil.com
```

if you include the slash in your base URL (better practise). These are safe as all it does is pass your website `evil.com` as a query string value because `@evil.com` will no longer be interpretted as a domain by the parser.

> What is the worst case scenario if even newlines are left in and the user can arbitrarily manipulate the HTTP headers?

This depends on how good your `http_get` function is at sanitizing values. If `http_get` does not strip newlines internally it could be possible for an attacker to control the headers sent from your application.

e.g. If `http_get` internally created the following request

```
GET <url> HTTP/1.1
Host: <url.domain>
```

so under legitimate use it would work like the following:

```
http_get("https://example.com/foo/bar")
```

generates

```
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

an attacker could set `params_str_submitted_by_user` to

```
<space>HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.org\r\nCookie: foo=bar\r\n\r\n
```

this would cause your code to call

```
http_get("https://example.com/" + "?" + "<space>HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.org\r\nCookie: foo=bar\r\n\r\n")
```

which would cause the request to be

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Cookie: foo=bar

 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Depending on how `http_get` parses the domain this might not cause the request to go to `example.org` instead of `example.com` - it is just manipulating the header (unless `example.org` was another site *on the same IP address* as your site). However, the attacker has managed to manipulate headers and add their own cookie value. The advantage to the attacker depends on what can be gained under your particular setup from them doing this - there is not necessarily any general advantage, it would be more of a logic flaw exploit if they could trick your code into behaving in an unexpected way by causing it to make requests under the control of the attacker.

### What should you do?

To guard against the unexpected and unknown, either use a version of `http_get` that handles header injection properly. Many modern languages now deal with this situation internally.

Or - if `http_get` is your own implementation, make sure it sanitizes or rejects URLs that contain invalid characters like carriage returns or line feeds and other parameters that are invalid in a URL. [See this question for list of valid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/413180).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I believe that it's always better to handle sanitization explicitly than to expect an external library to do it "automatically"